# Cassandra RPC Timeout on import from CSV

Tags: csv, cassandra, cqlsh

I am trying to import a CSV into a column family in Cassandra using the following syntax:

```
copy data (id, time, vol, speed, occupancy, status, flags) from 'C:\Users\Foo\Documents\reallybig.csv' with header = true;
```

The CSV file is about 700 MB, and for some reason when I run this command in cqlsh I get the following error:

"Request did not complete within rpc_timeout."

What is going wrong? There are no errors in the CSV, and it seems to me that Cassandra should be suck in this CSV without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra installation folder has a .yaml file to set rpc timeout value which is "rpc_timeout_in_ms ", you could modify the value and restart cassandra.

But another way is cut your big csv to multiply files and input the files one by one.

Answer (score 1):

This actually ended up being my own misinterpretation of `COPY-FROM` as the CSV was about 17 million rows. Which in this case the best option was to use the bulk loader example and run `sstableloader`. However, the answer above would certainly work if I wanted to break the CSV into 17 different CSV's which is an option.